# Set the margin or padding between two images next to eachother

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the margin or padding between two image which are next to eachother, somehow the margin seems to be also 40%, namely the width of one image. How to set my own margin/padding between the images of lets say 2px???

```css
.certifications, .car {
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.certifications img {
    max-width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}

.car img {
    max-width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}

#wrapper.car {
    max-width: 100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper car">
                        
                        <div class="car"><img alt=
                        "" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></div>
     
                        <div class="certifications"><img alt=
                        "" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100""></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You have a typo and a syntax problem: There's an extra `"` in the `.certifications img`, and each element can only have one id - `#wrapper.car` in your css isn't matching anything… it should be either `#wrapper` and `<div id="wrapper">` or `#wrapper.car` and `<div id="wrapper" class="car">` (but if you go with the second route, use a different class name otherwise the `#wrapper` will get unwanted styles from `.car`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `inline-block` to `inline`.  Then you can add a margin for spacing:

```css
.certifications, .car {
 display:inline;
    margin-right: 10px;
 position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.certifications img {
    max-width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}

.car img {
    max-width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}

#wrapper.car {
    max-width: 100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper car">
                        
                        <div class="car"><img alt=
                        "" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></div>
     
                        <div class="certifications"><img alt=
                        "" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100""></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to match the question. The images are 100px wide, while the question states that "the width of one image" is 40%. The resulting margins are also slightly bigger than styled, as is to be expected. And it retains the syntax errors in the op

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want each image to be 40% of the wrapper's width. Right now each image is 40% of the `#wrapper > div`'s width. I

- removed unnecessary styles from `#wrapper`
- made `.certifications` and `.car` 40% of the `#wrapper`'s width, given them spacing on the right, and made the images full width
- made `.certifications` and `.car` blocks, because whitespace in your html between inline-blocks will actually take up space in the rendered page
- changed max-widths to widths

```css
.certifications,
.car {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40%;
  padding-right: 20px;/* could also use margin */
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="car">
    <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
  </div>
  
  <div class="certifications">
    <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
  </div>
  
</div>
```